# ReSharper 5.1 can't navigate to a type from anywhere

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, resharper, resharper-5.x

I'm running Visual Studio 2010 (10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel) with ReSharper 5.1 (5.1.3000.12).  Recently, it seems as though ReSharper has completely lost the ability to navigate to a type.

Here are some actions I can take in the UI that now do nothing:

1. Right-click on type name in code
   editor and select "Go To
   Declaration"
2. Right-click on type name in code
   editor and select "Go To
   Implementation"
3. R# "Go to type" (Ctrl-T)
4. In the R# "Find Results" window, double-clicking a type

Here are some actions that still work:

1. Double-clicking an item in Solution Explorer
2. Opening a file from VS Command Window

I've completely uninstalled Visual Studio, then reinstalled it with SP1, and ReSharper 5.1, and I still have the same problem.

I'm assuming there's some kind of configuration open that I've done that is disabling the ability to navigate to a type with ReSharper, I just can't figure out what it is.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using VS 2010 SP1 (same as you)

Delete the Resharper temp files in the same location as your solution file. The folder name will be something like `_ReSharper.SomeSolution`

Failing that, try one of the R# nightly builds [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+6.0+Nightly+Builds) altho it should work with your current config.

Comment: Ok, I've tried deleting all of the _ReSharper files and directories and restarted VS, but I'm still having the same problem.  About to try the latest nightly build.

Comment: I installed the nightly build of R# 6 and the problem is solved!

Comment: @Paul glad it is working for you just recall that the EAP builds expire after 30 days; you can either re-install with a later EAP build or upgrade to R#6 if it is production.

Answer (score 3):

I just experienced this problem. None of the previous suggestions worked for me unfortunately, but I managed to resolve it:

1. Go to Resharper -> Options
2. Under Keyboard Shortcuts, temporarily switch to a different scheme than the one selected
3. Press 'Apply Scheme' button then press Save
4. hen repeat, but this time select the scheme you actually want and press 'Apply Scheme'

Hopefully that fixes it!